# JS\TS - unable to add a white space in a string based on multiple special characters

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I'm looking for a smart way to add white space after special character in a long string.

```
let str = "this\is\an\example\for\a\long\string";
str = str.split("\\").join("\\ ");
```

This would produce:

```
"this\ is\ an\ example\ for\ a\ long\ string";
```

I am looking for something more generic to capture multiple special chars at once, something like this:

```
let str = "this.is.a\long-mixed.string\with\many.special/characters";
str = str.split(/[.\-_]/).join(/[. \- _ ]/); //note the white spaces after the dot, hyphen and slash. I need to cover as much special chars as possible.
```

EDIT
I need this to support multi languages. So basically English\Arabic\Hebrew words should not be whitespaced, But only insert a whitespace after a special char.

Comment: Your string has multiple invalid escape sequences (and a couple of valid ones). Perhaps you meant `let str = "this\\is\\an\\example\\for\\a\\long\\string";` or ``let str = String.raw`this\is\an\example\for\a\long\string`;`` ?

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote, since I get a scraped string, which can exist in any form, mixed between slashes and backslashes.

Comment: No, you've shown **source code** for a string. If you wanted to just show the string, just show the string: `this\is\an\example\for\a\long\string`. There's a difference between a string literal and the actual string contents. Your string literal in the question does not code the string you apparently receive. For example, the word "for" doesn't exist in the string created by the literal shown in the question.

Comment: Im not entirely following you, `this\is\an\example\for\a\long\string` is an example of a string that can be returned from the server

Comment: Right. And if you want to show that string as a string literal in the code in your question, you have to escape those backslashes. The literal in the question describes a string containing these characters: `thisisanexample<FF>oralongstring` where `<FF>` is a formfeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

So here with replace i am matching anything except alphabets and digits. and than simply adding a space to it.

```js
let str = "this.is.a\long-mixed.string\with\many.special/characters";
str = str.replace(/([\W_])/g, "$1 ");
console.log(str);
```

`([\W_])` - Matches anything except alphabets and digits.

Comment: Great! can you please explain the logic behind this regex? in case I want to modify this in the future?

Comment: @undroid i have added a explanation. check the updated answer.

Comment: This spits words as well, can this code be modified to support multilingual strings? English\Arabic\Hebrew for example

Comment: @undroid yes you can but for that you have to make more changes to regex.this regex will work for English alphabets